# Generic static fields initialization

Tags: c#, generics, static

I'm just getting curious about the following code :

```
public static class Container<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] EmptyArray = new T[0];
}
```

As I've understood the static class Container will be initialized when the following code executes:

```
...
var emptyArray = Container<int>.EmptyArray;
...
```

Am I right ? Any explanations on static generic classes/members initialization would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guarantee is that the static field is initialized before you access it. (And also, if there is also a static constructor, then all static fields will be initialized before the static constructor is run.)

For generic classes, static initialization works on a per-type basis, so `Container<int>` acts as if it is a completely different class to `Container<double>`. This is actually true for all static parts of a generic class - each type gets its own 'copy'.

An example will show this last point more clearly:

```
static class Foo<T>
{
    static int count = 0;
    public static int Increment()
    {
        return ++count;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo<int>.Increment());
        Console.WriteLine(Foo<int>.Increment());
        Console.WriteLine(Foo<double>.Increment());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Oh, so the answer is "yes" :)

Answer (score 5):

Static field initializers are really moved into the static constructor (type initializer) of the class. So your code compiles into this automagically:

```
public static class Container<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] EmptyArray;

    static Container()
    {
        EmptyArray = new T[];
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) about static constructors:

> It [Static Constructor] is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Since `Container<string>` and `Container<bool>` are not the same, the static constructor is called once for each type of `T`.

Comment: I misunderstood the static constructor idea - I thought that static constructors are called at the very start of program, so this code sample seemed pretty weird to me. Thanks.

Comment: @danyloid: The runtime is allowed to call the static constructor at any time before members of the class are used. This *could* be at the start of the program, or just before you actually use it for the first time.